# WD My Cloud vs Buffalo LS210D

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, nas, cloud

I also suffer very slow speeds with the My Cloud.  It replaces a Buffalo LS210D which I thought was slow; not in this comparison.
Nothing else in my set-up has changed; I have a laptop "fixed" to a power supply in my lounge, one floor down and 1 room across from the Router and NAS.  From the laptop to the Buffalo, a 30meg file took 10 to 15 seconds to "beam up"; on the My Cloud, the same file takes 3 minutes!
I was ready to return it as faulty!  BUT, the odd thing is the wired PC, cabled to the router via Gigabit port and Cat 6 cable, as is the My Cloud to the router, writes at about 50MB/s and reads around 100MB/s... that's about the same as the Buffalo.
So, why on earth is the My Cloud via Wi-Fi 12 times slower than the Buffalo and yet the cabled device is just fine?
I'm sure someone knows the answer and I'll kick myself when I realise how daft I've been; that sounds like a challenge to me... anyone?
Regards,
Mike

Comment: Take a deep breath, visualize that you are a total stranger who doesn't know you from Adam and has never seen your place or configuration.  Now start from the beginning, leave out extraneous commentary, and provide some context.  Explain the setup in an organized way.  Describe what you are trying to do.  Describe the issue or problem.  Break all of this into logical paragraphs.  Think about how your question could be useful to others and try to reflect that in how and what you write.  Hopefully, that will result in something clear that people can respond to in a way that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact model of the WD My Cloud device that you have?

What are the dashboard settings and firmware that you are using?

How are you transferring files to the WD My Cloud (My Cloud application, Network Shared folder in File Explorer, etc.)?

Have you tried multiple wireless devices to see if the distance from the router or the device itself makes any difference to the transfer speeds?

Check the settings of your router if there's a limitation to the available bandwidth towards either the NAS or the laptop when and if it has a lower signal.

Try transferring the same file from multiple devices and at multiple distances from the router.

Check the health of the WD My Cloud through the dashboard tools (both HDD and system settings). Let me know if you need help with that!

Post back with some more info and progress!

Comment: I will reply as soon as I've written it out in Word... because I'm always hitted ENTER and that seems to publish my answer rather than go to the next line; that annoys me so give me a little time and I'll post a reponse soon.  Thanks.

Comment: The exact model is WDBCTL0020HWT-10 & the F/W is v2.21.111
I have 2 shares set-up; one is for streaming to a TV & Yamaha AVR, so DNLA Media Server is ON for that one, and the other is a folder for backing up my desktop PC (wired) and 2 laptops.
For single file back-up, I drag-and-drop to the SHARE folder.
All other back-ups are done using GFI Home Backup.
My obvious question is why would changing the NAS slow down the Wi-Fi by such a huge margin?
Mike

Comment: That is indeed weird. Do you have another router at hand to test if the same thing happens? 
Did you try moving the laptops closer to the router and see if the speed improves? 
Did the swapping of the devices cause the router to set a connection limit per device on the wireless network?

Comment: I placed my laptop next to my router (no spare sadly) & transfered a 30 meg file & noted a 5mb/s speed. I took the laptop back to its usual place &, strangely, the speed was the same!  I use Money 2005 &, when you close it down, it offers to back up the data file; once a month, I do.  It used to take 10-15 seconds & now 3 mins. Nothing has changed in months... it was literally one NAS out, one NAS in!  As to the connection limit per device, I don't really know how to check that.  Mike.

Comment: If the NAS has the latest firmware update and the wired speeds are good I'd suggest contacting our live support and see if the guys can do something about it: http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=TOlkxZ

Comment: Thanks Captain_WD... I will, however, have to check out those 00800 International so-called free numbers because I don't think it will actually be free from my mobile as I don't have a landline.  If, as I suspect, my mobile company charge for them at the International rate, then the call "ain't gonna happen" but thanks for the information anyway!

Comment: No problem, let me know if I can do anything else for you. Posting a topic in the official WD forum about this is also an option.